# how do I scrape unicode text properly?

Tags: python, web-scraping, encoding, utf-8, farsi

I'm trying to scrape this list of options:

```py
from lxml import html 
import requests as req

ifb_resp = req.get(
    url='https://www.ifb.ir/ThirdMarket/AllUnderWrited.aspx',
    headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
             'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,fa;q=0.8'})
tree= html.fromstring(html=ifb_resp.content)
instruments = tree.xpath('//select[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_SymbolCombo"]/option')
a1 = instruments[1]
print(a1.text)
```

but the text element is in Farsi(Persian) and it comes out like this:
‍‍‍`' Ø§Ø¹ØªØ¶Ø§Ø¯ ØºØ¯Û\x8cØ±1_Ø¨Ø§Ø²Ø§Ø± Ø³Ù\x88Ù\x85'`

I tried encoding it with 'utf-8' and got this:
`b' \xc3\x98\xc2\xa7\xc3\x98\xc2\xb9\xc3\x98\xc2\xaa\xc3\x98\xc2\xb6\xc3\x98\xc2\xa7\xc3\x98\xc2\xaf \xc3\x98\xc2\xba\xc3\x98\xc2\xaf\xc3\x9b\xc2\x8c\xc3\x98\xc2\xb11_\xc3\x98\xc2\xa8\xc3\x98\xc2\xa7\xc3\x98\xc2\xb2\xc3\x98\xc2\xa7\xc3\x98\xc2\xb1 \xc3\x98\xc2\xb3\xc3\x99\xc2\x88\xc3\x99\xc2\x85'`

why does it turn into binary?!!!! I'm so lost here. how do I get the text as it is on the page?

[the page which I'm scraping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFqag.png)
[comes out like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElrPQ.png)

Comment: Your `url` can’t be reached in my browser. However, you face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case: `' Ø§Ø¹ØªØ¶Ø§Ø¯ ØºØ¯Û\x8cØ±1_Ø¨Ø§Ø²Ø§Ø± Ø³Ù\x88Ù\x85' .encode('latin1') .decode('utf8')` returns `' اعتضاد غدیر1_بازار سوم'`…

Comment: In `ifb_resp.headers` are there "conent-xxx" fileds, like content-encoding? The html may not have the correct encoding but the http may. In that case, `html=ifb_resp.text` may work.

Comment: thank you @JosefZ . it's exactly right. that's it.
btw, the problem with the `url` is probably because of the policies of Iran's toxic government. which blocks foreign traffic outside of working hours! anyway, thanks a bunch mate. u made my day.

Comment: yes, there are @tdelaney . but that's not the problem. the problem was the issue that >JosefZ mentioned and solved. thanks for the help anyway. 

Comment: how do I mark the question as *solved* now? it's my first question on StackOverflow. 

Comment: @Josef2 could turn the comment into an answer, but its perfectly okay to just answer it yourself. Write the answer and then accept.

Comment: Yes, post the answer yourself, and accept it. Also, since there is no guarantee that the comments will persist, please update your question to show the source data in Farsi. That will be helpful for future readers of your question.